# How to check each value in an array is empty?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

If I have an array:

```
$nav = array($nav_1, $nav_2, $nav_3);
```

and want to check if they are empty with a loop (the real array is much bigger), so that it checks each variable separately, how do I do it?

I want something like this;

```
$count = 0;

while(count < 3){
     if(empty($nav[$count])) //the loops should go through each value (nav[0], nav[1] etc.)
          //do something
          $count = $count+1;
     }else{
          //do something
          $count = $count+1;
     }
}
```

Comment: You can use `in_array()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty straight-forward with a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($nav as $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        // empty
        $count++;
    } else {
        // not empty
    }
}

echo 'There were total ', $count, ' empty elements';
```

If you're trying to check if **all** the values are empty, then use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
if (!array_filter($nav)) {
    // all values are empty
}
```

Comment: I would also say to OP that depending on how your array is built you may need to clean and sanitize the string less things like whitespace get written and cause you headaches further down the road.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you can check if all variables are empty in your array. Is this what you are looking for?

```
$eachVarEmpty = true;

foreach($nav as $item){
    // if not empty set $eachVarEmpty to false and go break of the loop
    if(!empty(trim($item))){
        $eachVarEmpty = false;
        // go out the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$empty = array_reduce($array, function(&$a,$b){return $a &= empty($b);},true);
```