# Check if all items of array are empty

Tags: php

I'm beginner in the PHP programming. Please can somebody suggest me any trick? How could I shorten this script with any cycle function?

```
$org[1] = $_POST['name'];
$org[2] = $_POST['street'];
$org[3] = $_POST['city'];
$org[4] = $_POST['postal_code'];
$org[5] = $_POST['org_nmr'];
$org[6] = $_POST['tin'];

if (
    (empty($org[1])) 
    && (empty($org[2])) 
    && (empty($org[3])) 
    && (empty($org[4])) 
    && (empty($org[5])) 
    && (empty($org[6]))
) {
    echo 'Not enter have no data';
}
```

I think that it is possible to make it somehow. But I don't know how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check each value in an array is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203149/how-to-check-each-value-in-an-array-is-empty)

Comment: I wonder how this question can get five upvotes. And only you don't know must not mean you need to ask. First search (the suggested duplicate is not very well chosen I must admit).

Comment: PS> you should always start your count with 0 NOT 1 ... moreover, you shouldn't have to do it like this, you should have corresponding names in your array  $org["name"] = _$POST['name'], etc.

Answer (score 2):

This simple answer is tailored to  user's example question (it does not take into account arrays whose values are arrays/objects etc).

```
$data = trim(implode('',$org));
if (strlen($data) === 0){ 
 ... 
}
```

I changed from empty($data) to strlen($data) === 0 in if condition in case that having value zero is a non empty situation for you; because as we know empty($data) will be true when $data = '0')

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) built in function,

```
if(count(array_filter($_POST)) == 0)
   echo 'Nezadal(a) jste žádné údaje';
```

Comment: No, I meant [`'0'` is considered falsely](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), which `array_filter` will filter out if no callback function is passed, i. e., `array_filter(array('0')) === array()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid repetition with a loop. It might also make more sence to keep the named associative array rather than a numerically indexed one for `$org`.

```
$org = array();
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
  If (! empty($value)) {
    $org[$name] = $value;
  }
}
If (empty($org)) { //... Error here
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do that check before you access any Key in the POST array.

Required no loop at all, that foreach is just used to output missing keys, not to do the check

```
<?php
$required = array_flip(array('key_a', 'key_b')); // list of required keys, just used array_flip for ease of writing
$post = array('key_a' => 'a value'); // your $_POST array
$check = array_diff_key($required, $post);
if(!empty($check))  {
   // foreach not required as answer to your question, just to point missing keys out.
   foreach($check as $key => $value) {
       echo $key, 'key is missing!', PHP_EOL;
   }
   die('Some message');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array('name', 'street', 'city', 'postal_code', 'org_nmr', 'tin');
$getLength = function($val, $post_data){
    return is_null($post_data[$val]) ? 0 : strlen($post_data[$val]);
};
if(array_sum(array_map($getLength, $values, $_POST)) == 0){
    echo 'Nezadal(a) jste žádné údaje';
}
```

Basically you create a function which will determine the length of an array element and return it's length.

You then map this function to all all elements and then sum it.

- [array_sum php doc](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-sum.php)
- [array_map php doc](https://www.php.net/array_map)

Answer (score 0):

surprised nobody mentioned in_array ?

```
if (in_array("", (array) $org)) {
   echo "something is empty in this array";
}
```

A take on the person's above, I would cast $org perhaps :

```
$test = trim(implode('', (array) $org));
if (strlen($test) === 0){ 
   ... 
}
```

More examples:

```
$arr0 = array('Hello', 'World!', 'Beautiful', 'Day!');
$arr1 = array("something" => 'here');
$arr2 = array("something" => '');
$arr3 = array();
$arr4 = "string";
$arr5 = 34;
$arr6 = '';

$test = trim(implode('', (array)$arr0));
if (strlen($test) === 0) {
    echo "No data in this array";
} else {
    echo "Data in this array \n";
}


$test = trim(implode('', (array)$arr1));
if (strlen($test) === 0) {
    echo "No data in this array\n";
} else {
    echo "Data in this array \n";
}

$test = trim(implode('', (array)$arr2));
if (strlen($test) === 0) {
    echo "No data in this array\n";
} else {
    echo "Data in this array \n";
}

$test = trim(implode('', (array)$arr3));
if (strlen($test) === 0) {
    echo "No data in this array\n";
} else {
    echo "Data in this array \n";
}

$test = trim(implode('', (array)$arr4));
if (strlen($test) === 0) {
    echo "No data in this array\n";
} else {
    echo "Data in this array \n";
}

$test = trim(implode('', (array)$arr5));
if (strlen($test) === 0) {
    echo "No data in this array\n";
} else {
    echo "Data in this array \n";
}


$test = trim(implode('', (array)$arr6));
if (strlen($test) === 0) {
    echo "No data in this array\n";
} else {
    echo "Data in this array \n";
}
```